# How to get more/optional data for users using keyclaok rest api?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

We are using Keycloak for SSO purpose, in particular we are able to use the REST API `/admin/realms/{realm}/users` to get the basic user details in a Keycloak realm, the response we get is **UserRepresentation** which seems to have provision for **realmRoles** and **clientRoles** as well but by default they are not required/false.

We have a new requirement to fetch the roles of all users, I see there are additional API exposed to get these roles: `/auth/admin/realms/realm/users/user-id/role-mappings/realm/`, but this means firing another request, and if we have 2k users that means 2k more request.

My question is as **UserRepresentation** also have properties **realmRoles** and **clientRoles** but seems to be optional by default, how can I enable these while firing the request `/admin/realms/{realm}/users`, and avoid additional request to get roles.

Comment: Have you tried   GET /admin/clients/{id}/roles

Comment: It needs user id, if you want 2k user roles it needs 2k requests fired, not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that getting the data you need in one request is not possible: just by looking at the source code of getting all users in [UsersResource](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java) you can see that `realmRoles` and `clientRoles` are never populated.

Having that said, there is one thing that you can do - write your own [REST Resource by implementing SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_rest). In fact, in the past I had a similar problem with groups resource and I ended up writing my own resource. In this case you will need to write custom resource with just one method - getting all users with roles. You can just copy-paste current keycloak logic and add extra bits or extend built-in UsersResource. This, however, is not a single bullet - on the long run you will be required to maintain your own code and upgrades to latest keycloak may not be that simple if some interface will change.